# Options to remove or modify AspNet Identity

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am developing asp.net mvc web application with Entity Framework 6.1.3. 
The asp.net identity that comes by default seemed fine to me until my boss said we cannot make any changes to the database tables (users, user roles) to fit with aspnet identity, as it is a legacy db..as is described here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elfqejow5hM

So, what are my options now? 
can i totally remove aspnet identity? how?
can i tell my identitycontext that my table names and columns are different and also change the behaviour in rolemanager?

On top of all this, my database is a mysql db Cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A default ASP.NET MVC project with Individual User Accounts, comes with a middleware named Owin, which in short allows a lot of authentication configs for your app, like:

- Cookies Authentication
- Cookies External Auth
- Two Factor SignIn (e.g a password + code in mobile by sms)
- Facebook Authentication
- OAuth Bearer Token
- etc...

Meanwhile, Identity is a library built to mix various old memberships, thus allowing you to work with many ASP.NET frameworks, such as ASP.NET MVC, WebForms, etc. Moreover, it comes with a built-in implementation, which also works as a provider for owin capabilities. Though, Identity is all based on interfaces, so developers can easily customize anything there, like plugging/unplugging features. This is just a short description.

> So, what are my options now?

1. Use Identity's built-in engine, it'll create **new tables** for itself (including AspNetUsers and AspNetRoles), which you **won't mix** with your existing tables. Inside `Models` folder, there is an `IdentityModels.cs` file, with an `ApplicationDbContext` class, inheriting `IdentityDbContext`. Bring your existing `DbSet` for your models there (including for the existing user and role). You can create a relationship between the `ApplicationUser` (which comes by default with a brand new project, representing an `IdentityUser`) and your existing User. So you won't affect your existing tables at all.
2. You can implement all Identity's interfaces by your own (not that hard, but it takes some time to understand), then you could make your existing `User` and `Role` implement respectively `IUser` and `IRole` to combine with Identity.
3. You can make your existing models for `User` and `Role` just inherit `IdentityUser` and `IdentityRole`. After this, naturally your `ApplicationDbContext` would like to insert/update some columns in your tables to fit `IdentityUser` and `IdentityRole` models (since your classes now inherit from them), then you might want to configure it to avoid changing your existing tables.

> Can i totally remove aspnet identity?

Sure you can. If you don't need all that Owin's features at all, you might not even use it, for sake of simplicity.

> How?

You could just create a new project with **Forms Authentication** rather than **Individual User Accounts**, and implement a custom `RoleProvider` to interact with your existing `Role`. It's kinda easy to implement a custom `RoleProvider` for forms authentication. You can make your provider check for roles by querying your tables, or consuming a webservice, it's up to you.

> Can i tell my identitycontext that my table names and columns are
>   different and also change the behaviour in rolemanager?

Sure. Override the `OnModelCreating` method in your `ApplicationDbContext` (the same one which inherits `IdentityDbContext`) to change all its default behaviour when generating/updating database. You might not call `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);`, because this is what creates a lot of configs for your tables.

---

I suggest you to start reading about [ASP.NET Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) and maybe [Using MySQL Storage with an MySQL EF Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider), so you can decide whether you keep Identity, customize it, remove it, etc.

Comment: Thanks! This was what i was looking for...I am going with "create a relationship between the ApplicationUser and your existing User." option. and i have overriden the onmodelbuilder method to adjust... On a totally different note can i tell my code to add only identity tables and migrations table if they donot exist in the existing database? instead of dropping the database and creating it again

Comment: @Samra EF doesn't do this by default. EF6 do this if you setup a initializer with `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`. Look for this word in your entire project. If you find it, you might want to remove it.

Comment: I am using customDBinitialzer "MySqlInitialzer" and i have an existing db, so EF tries to find aspnetusers table in that db on first login/register which it doesnt and i dont want to drop the whole db and say context.Database.Create(); so i have manually created these tables for now and was wondering if i could tell EF to create only identity tables and not touch other tables

Comment: could you please answer my related question? i am really stuck here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617017/how-to-link-one-to-one-relationship-when-fk-is-different-from-pk-entityframewo

Comment: @Samra ok, I'm gonna answer it. About recreating databases, take a look [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/788357/How-to-set-up-application-using-ASP-NET-Identity-w) how to avoid it.