# How to link one-to-one relationship when fk is different from pk - EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, entity-relationship, dbcontext

I have a custom users table in my database and i want to create a one-to-one relationship with aspnetusers table so that when i register a new customer, applicationuser class through UserManager should add the **username, email, password and school code** to the users table and add an fk in its own table. IS there any tutorial/example implementing this kind of scenario?

I am trying to add a one-to-one relationship with my users table but the fk is different than pk

- Users Table [columns]

  - username
  - password
  - school code
  - userId [pk]

ASPNETUsers Table [standard columns]

- Id, [pk]
- UserName,
- PasswordHash,
- SecurityStamp,
- Discriminator,
- Email,
- EmailConfirmed,
- PhoneNumber,
- PhoneNumberConfirmed,
- TwoFactorEnabled,
- LockoutEndDateUtc,
- LockoutEnabled,
- AccessFailedCount
- userId [fk to users table]

I have added property inside **ApplicationUser** class

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual User user { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
          .HasRequired(i => i.user).WithRequiredDependent(i => i.appUser);
      }

}

 public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser appUser { get; set; }
}
```

What else do i need to do and is it correct? How does entityframework work with this one?

I have tried to explain My application structure here: [image]

**UPDATE**
On running it gives me error
 MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unknown column 'Extent8.appUser_Id' in 'on clause'

If I define

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasKey(u => u.UserID);
```

inside **OnModelCreating** then it tries to link AspNetRoles and Claims etc tables through this UserID and ofcourse crashes.

ApplicationUser_Claims_Source_ApplicationUser_Claims_Target: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'UserId' on entity 'IdentityUserClaim' does not match the type of property 'UserID' on entity 'ApplicationUser' in the referential constraint 'ApplicationUser_Claims'.
ApplicationUser_Logins_Source_ApplicationUser_Logins_Target: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'UserId' on entity 'IdentityUserLogin' does not match the type of property 'UserID' on entity 'ApplicationUser' in the referential constraint 'ApplicationUser_Logins'.
ApplicationUser_Roles_Source_ApplicationUser_Roles_Target: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'UserId' on entity 'IdentityUserRole' does not match the type of property 'UserID' on entity 'ApplicationUser' in the referential constraint 'ApplicationUser_Roles'.

Comment: Done. I hope you have enough patience, understand my explanations and read the links I recommended. Good luck!!!

Comment: Thanks a bunch Alisson! I was stuck since two days!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How EF's one-to-one relationship works, in short...

When working with **one-to-one** relationship, Entity Framework uses the parent's `Id` column in the child as the FK to the parent, it won't create a second column for FK because that would be considered **one-to-many** relationship, because that second column would allow a parent `Id` to exist in many child entries, whereas the PK as FK wouldn't.

### How should I configure both keys?

Since your `ApplicationUser` inherits from `IdentityUser`, it will use it's existing properties and relationships. It already defines an `Id` column, so creating `UserId` is not necessary, as well as trying to make `UserId` the **key** property. You should use the existing `Id` column, which by default is `string` and it looks your existing `User` table has an `integer` PK, so they don't match.

However, this is not the end of the world. Identity's built-in implementation uses `string` as key for their classes (*AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles, etc...*) but they allows us to use another type of primary key.

### So...what should I do?

Identity defines two classes for each table, so there are two `IdentityUser` classes, two `IdentityRole`, and so on. One is the base generic class, which accepts some **generics**. The other is the **built-in implementation** of that base class, which supplies those generic types.

This **base class** looks like this:

```
public class IdentityUser<TKey, TLogin, TRole, TClaim> : IUser<TKey>
        where TLogin : IdentityUserLogin<TKey>
        where TRole : IdentityUserRole<TKey>
        where TClaim : IdentityUserClaim<TKey>
```

The first generic type is `TKey`, which defines the key's type, which is `string`. The second is a `TLogin`, which is a `IdentityUserLogin<TKey>`, which means it should be some class inheriting `IdentityUserLogin` using the same `TKey` type used as key (maybe `string`, maybe an `int`).

Meanwhile, the built-in implementation for these base classes looks like this:

```
public class IdentityUser 
    : IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>, IUser, IUser<string> {}
```

Which defines `TKey` as a `string` to be used as key. The other generics like `IdentityUserLogin` and `IdentityUserRole`, are built-in classes implementing the base classes which a `string` key. Take a look how `IdentityUserRole` looks like:

```
public class IdentityUserRole  IdentityUserRole<string> {}
```

See? `string` as well. Many other classes use `string` as default for `TKey`.

So if you were to change your class like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
{
    public virtual User user { get; set; }
}
```

It wouldn't work yet, because we changed `TKey` to be `int`, but the built-in `IdentityUserLogin` still uses `string`. So we need to create our own `IdentityUserLogin` like this:

```
public class MyNiceUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int>
{
}
```

...and use it like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, MyNiceUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
{
    public virtual User user { get; set; }
}
```

...but we still had to do the same with the other classes like `IdentityUserRole` and `IdentityUserClaim`.

### I configured it to use `int`. Now what about one-to-one relationship?

Your code here:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
      .HasRequired(i => i.user).WithRequiredDependent(i => i.appUser);
}
```

...works fine. You're configuring in a way both **must** exist, there is no `ApplicationUser` without a `User` and vice-versa.

---

Now, I recommend you read [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34505904/change-user-id-type-to-int-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs2015) to know exactly what steps to follow in order to change Identity's classes to use `int` as key.

> I also **strongly recommend** you to read [this post](http://johnatten.com/2014/07/13/asp-net-identity-2-0-extending-identity-models-and-using-integer-keys-instead-of-strings/) by John Atten, so you
>   can understand deeply about how to customize/extend Identity.

Comment: This is really elaborate and well defined answer